# Looking up an element or checking if it exists in an array/list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to this and I don't really understand how this works.

I have made a list which stores information about a room:

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each room stores data of its room number(integer), type(enum), price(double), capacity(integer) and facilities(string).

Long story short, my  questions are:

**(1) How can I search this list and e.g. check if say room with number '401' exists or not?**

**(2) How can I print out every single room and its information that there is?**

---

Extra info:

I can add a room by doing:

```
Room r = new Room(roomNumber, roomType, price, capacity, facilities);
rooms.add(r);
```

(I have made a 'Room' class with a constructor and methods like getRoomNumber()...).

I found out I can search the 'rooms' list and bring up information about a room that I know which exists, e.g. room with roomNumber 101:

```
// Info for room '101'

Room room = rooms.stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getRoomNumber() == 101)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow();

System.out.println("Room Number: " + room.getRoomNumber());
System.out.println("Type: " + room.getRoomType());
System.out.println("Cost: " + room.getPrice());
System.out.println("Capacity: " + room.getCapacity());
System.out.println("Facilities: " + room.getFacilities());
```

The above code works correctly.

I tried using the above with try and catch to see if a room exists (if it doesn't it throws a NoSuchElementFound exception) but that doesn't seem to work at all, the code doesn't even compile.

I also tried using (with and without valueOf):

```
Arrays.asList(rooms).contains(Integer.valueOf(401))
```

but that doesn't really work. The code compiles but it doesn't really do anything.

So, my questions (as mentioned before) are:

(1) How can I search this list and e.g. check if say room with number '401' exists or not?

(2) How can I print out every single room and its information that there is?

Thanks!

Comment: use a Stream, map the element(s) for which the number is 401 and check: ifPresent.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check for a specific room and throw an `Exception` if it doesn't exist then you need to provide the `Exception` supplier to `orElseThrow()` method, e.g.:

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
Room room = rooms.stream()
        .filter(r -> r.getRoomNumber() == 101)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about starting with this approach ?
Define a `public String toString() { ... }` for your Room class that prints out all values and then do this:

```
for( Room room: rooms ) {

   System.out.println("Room: " + room);
   if( room.getRoomNumber()==401 ) System.out.println("found !");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using a simple `for-loop` to iterate over it or use the `iterator`.

```
public boolean roomExists(List<Room> rooms, int roomNumber) {
  Iterator<Room> itr = rooms.iterator();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Room room = itr.next();
    if (ruoomNumber == room.getRoomNumber()) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I would recommend using `iterator` as they do not fail-fast and streams should not be used in case of small sized arrays.

**See medium blog post which does a benchmarking [here](https://medium.com/@swayamraina/should-you-really-use-streams-6709a869aed3).**

For the second part, You should override the `toString()` method of the `Room` class.

```
public String toString() {
   return this.roomNumber + this.name + ... ;  // so on
}
```

And create a function to list the details,

```
public void printData (List<Room> rooms) {
Iterator<Room> itr = rooms.iterator();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Room room = itr.next();
    System.out.println(room);
  }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn‘t hurt to at least add some spaces between the rooms properties in the toString method...

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a relevant getter method in your Room class :

```
for (Room room : rooms) {
   if (room.getRoomNumber() == 401) System.out.println("Room 401 found");
}
```

for printing all rooms in the arraylist (using your Room class toString() method)

```
for (Room room : rooms) { System.out.println(room); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
int findRoomNumber = 101;

 Room result = rooms.stream()
               .filter(r -> r.getRoomNumber() == findRoomNumber)
               .findFirst()
               .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Room not found : " + findRoomNumber));
```

Your code is not compiling because you are not passing `Supplier` to `orElseThrow` method.

Answer (score 2):

> (1) How can I search this list and e.g. check if say room with number
>   '401' exists or not?

```
boolean roomExists = rooms.stream().anyMatch(r->r.getRoomNumber() == 401);
```

> (2) How can I print out every single room and its information that
>   there is?

Add a toString method in your Room class if it doesn't yet exists:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Room{" + "roomNumber=" + roomNumber + ", roomType=" + roomType + ", price=" + price + ", capacity=" + capacity + ", facilities=" + facilities + '}';
}
```

To print each room from your rooms list :

```
rooms.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```